# Oauth2 Client & Open ID Connect in Flutter - Authorization Code Grant Type

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, oauth-2.0

So most of the tutorials that go over Authorization just use Firebase's Auth, and most of the backend work is taken care of.

I need to create an OAuth Client in Dart/Flutter for Intuit's Quickbooks Online.

My basic understanding is when a user launches my Flutter Web Application, I pop up a screen to initiate the Authorization Code Grant - OAuth.

They sign into Intuit Quickbooks using this pop-up screen, then grant my application permission.

At this point my application should receive an Authorization Code.

I am guessing that I need to store this Authorization Code in my Google Cloud Firestore?

I need to send this Authorization Code back to Intuit & receive 2 things: An Access Token & a Refresh Token.

I think I should also store these in the Cloud Firestore?

But I don't see where cloud functions fit into this picture. Do I use the cloud functions to write/read to the Cloud Firestore?

How do I handle user sessions? I need to address State management as well.

I am starting to understand why many people just use built-in, out-of-the-box functionality of Firebase Auth, because developing a custom OAuth Client in Dart/Flutter is a huge undertaking.

I'm starting to feel confused & lost. I need some suggestions, or organizing because I'm losing sight of what needs to revised, designed or developed.

**Main.dart**

```dart
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:html' as html;
import 'dart:convert';w
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';

Future main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  runApp(App());
}

class App extends StatefulWidget {
  // Create the initialization Future outside of `build`:
  @override
  _AppState createState() => _AppState();
}

class _AppState extends State<App> {
  final Future<FirebaseApp> _initialization = Firebase.initializeApp();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder(
      /// Initialize FlutterFire:
      future: _initialization,
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasError) {
          return Text(snapshot.error.toString());
        }

        /// Once complete, show your application
        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
          return MyApp();
        }
        /// Otherwise, show something whilst waiting for initialization to complete
        return CircularProgressIndicator();
      },
    );
  }
}


/// Client id provided by Intuit, our production app ClientID
const String clientId = "ABS0R9arxiHjNcAb0rP7OMs8aS1FRiMIINxOkhQimUPewGmQ2H";
const String clientSecret = "";

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  /// This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Title',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
        primaryColor: cPrimaryColor,

        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  late String _token;
  late html.WindowBase _popupWin;

  Future<String> _validateToken() async {
    final response = await http.get(
      Uri.parse('https://appcenter.intuit.com/connect/oauth2'),
      headers: {'Authorization': 'OAuth $_token'},
    );
    return (jsonDecode(response.body) as Map<String, dynamic>)['login']
        .toString();
  }

  void _login(String data) {
    /// Parse data to extract the token.
    final receivedUri = Uri.parse(data);

    /// Close the popup window
    if (_popupWin != null) {
      _popupWin.close();
      _popupWin == null; // changed = to ==
    }

    setState(() => _token = receivedUri.fragment
        .split('&')
        .firstWhere((e) => e.startsWith('access_token='))
        .substring('access_token='.length));
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    /// Listen to message send with `postMessage`.
    html.window.onMessage.listen((event) {
      /// The event contains the token which means the user is connected.
      if (event.data.toString().contains('access_token=')) {
        _login(event.data);
      }
    });

    /// You are not connected so open the Intuit authentication page.
    WidgetsBinding.instance!.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
      final currentUri = Uri.base;
      final redirectUri = Uri(
        host: currentUri.host,
        scheme: currentUri.scheme,
        port: currentUri.port,
        path: '/static.html',
      );
      final authUrl = //TODO add state=security_token
          'https://appcenter.intuit.com/connect/oauth2?client_id=ABS0R9arxiHjNcAb0rP7OMs8aS1FRiMIINxOkhQimUPewGmQ2H&response_type=code&scope=com.intuit.quickbooks.accounting&redirect_uri=https://google.com/&state=security_token%3D138r5719ru3e1%26url%3Dhttps://qb-payment-app.web.app/';
      _popupWin = html.window.open(
          authUrl, "Intuit QuickBooks Online Auth", "width=800, height=900, scrollbars=yes");
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('My App Bar'),
      )
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You asked a lot of questions here. I will address one of the statements:

> I am starting to understand why many people just use built-in, out-of-the-box functionality of Firebase Auth, because developing a custom OAuth Client in Dart/Flutter is a huge undertaking.

Actually it's pretty easy to implement custom OAuth client, please see this question where I've implemented my own google sign in service: [Flutter web google_sign_in: How to retrieve refreshToken](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69746035/flutter-web-google-sign-in-how-to-retrieve-refreshtoken/69746036#69746036)

You can customise this service to work with Quickbooks instead of Google SignIn.

Comment: The code you've provided on your link looks like it will be a very useful starting point for me! For whatever reason, writing the custom OAuth Client in Dart/Flutter has been really boggling my mind. I get so confused in the flow even though I've consumed so much educational & informative material on the topic. Thank you so much. I will review the link you've posted a little more in depth, and return with any issues I may experience.

Comment: My application is a web app, and cannot use the Oauth2 package because of the dart:io dependency, which is incompatible with Flutter Web.

Comment: I'm also using this service in a Flutter Web app. oauth2 package is compatible with Flutter Web: https://pub.dev/packages/oauth2

Comment: I must have misunderstood. Thank you for the clarification.